# Android Emulator broken when rotating display

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am facing an issue with the Android emulator.
When the emulator boots up everything is fine, regardless the default display orientation.
When I press one of the buttons to change the display orientation, the emulator window rotates but, the content is completely messed up.
See the pic below.
The same happens with all the AVDs I have created and with different android images.
I've already reinstalled/updated the emulator from package manager.
Any idea about why this is happening?

The work environment is:

- Mac OS Big Sur,
- Android Studio v4.1.1
- Android emulator v30.2.6

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This was a bug in the Google Android Emulator version 30.2.x.

It was fixed in version **30.3.5** (approximately 8 January 2021). Apply the update like this:

- Stop or Force Quit all the running AVD emulators
- Android Studio ➔ Tools ➔ SDK Manager ➔ SDK Tools (click this tab in the middle of the dialog) ➔ Android Emulator
- The status should say "Update Available"
- Click the Checkbox so that it will change from a horizontal line to a checkmark, and so that the download symbol appears on the left.

[image: Preferences Window for: Android Studio ➔ Tools ➔ SDK Manager ➔ SDK Tools]

- Click the <kbd>Apply</kbd> or <kbd>OK</kbd> button
- It should download version 30.3.5 or higher, for "Android Emulator".
- After the upgrade is applied, relaunch your emulators.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can confirm with the latest version the problem is fixed.

Comment: I was having the same problem with 30.3.5, but upgrading to the latest version (30.4.5) fixed it. Thanks for the answer. It saved us a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

Try running the emulator inside Android Studio. Go to settings-tools-emulator and check the box there to run the emulator inside Android Studio. When you rotate it after it should rotate faster than in the AVD's standalone application, and not break the display. This should fix the broken display problem, without making a new AVD. Make sure you have updated to the most recent version of Android Studio first, v4.1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried yo follow your suggestion and, when running inside Android studio and rotated, the display of the emulator doesn't break but it doesn't really rotate also. The emulator interface/device frame goes to landscape, but the content inside doesn't rotate despite the display rotation toggle being active.

Comment: Maybe on the emulator enable rotation in the drop down settings inside the emulated device, click auto rotate.

Comment: And if it is a newer AVD version, you may have to click the rotate button by the navigation buttons at the bottom of the AVD to rotate it.

Comment: Yes the enable rotation toggle in the drop down is enabled. But the content doesn't rotate anyway. The rotate button in the nav bar doesn't show up at all.

Answer (score 2):

The android emulator defaults to have auto rotate turned off. Turn on auto rotate the normal way you would on your phone and it will work.

Comment: Man! I've never thought I'd be so dumb.. thank you so much!